# UIButton background image used for animation not aligned across devices

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I have a UIButton backgroundImage that I use to display a weather condition image when the loading is complete. I also create a UIImageView that replaces the UIButton to animate a series of images as a progress indicator.

**My question: How can fix this animated `UIImageView` x-axis misalignment across multiple screen sizes?**

Here's what the sequence looks like on 4.7" iPhone, the red box indicates the image I'm talking about:

First, the UIImageView animating as a progress indicator (imagine it spinning, alignment is correct)

[image: 4.7" animating]

Second, the download complete, the progress indicator replaced by a UIButton with a backgroundImage:

[image: 4.7" image]

Third, the UIImageView animating on 4" iPhone (note misalignment on x-axis):

[image: 4" animating]

Fourth, the download complete, UIButton replaces it, aligned correctly:

[image: 4" image]

Here's how the `UIImageView *progressIndicator` is configured.
Note that `conditionButton` is the UIButton with backgroundImage of the weather condition:

```
self.progressIndicator = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.conditionButton.frame];

self.progressIndicator.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
self.progressIndicator.animationImages = @[...long series of images...];

self.progressIndicator.animationDuration = 0.5f;

[self.conditionButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"empty.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.progressIndicator startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:self.progressIndicator];
```

I'm pretty sure the issue is with

```
self.progressIndicator = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.conditionButton.frame];
```

But I'm not sure how to resolve this.

The same problem occurs when I switch to 5.5" iPhone. I have no Auto Layout warnings, and the constraints that apply to the conditionButton are:

```
Align Center X to superview
Width = 94
Height = 94
Bottom and Top space to nearest neighbor = default
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: had you check with bounds property...instead of `self.conditionButton.frame` use `self.conditionButton.bounds`

Comment: using `self.conditionButton.bounds` renders the animation at the origin (0,0) `bounds` refers to the extent of the view, where `frame` is the size of the view relative to its superview, right?